# Time Stamp In A Wordpress Post Title That Does Not Keep Refreshing

Tags: php, posts, shortcode, title, timestamp

I have a short-code that uses PHP to echo a time stamp ala: 1595140137
When I use that short-code as the default post title in new post, the post title changes with each page refresh, and in the browser title area, it just renders the short code characters. I have even double bracketed the short-code.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Well it changes because the time changes ;-) Is what you want for it to store the time when the post is created, and always show the time the post was created?

Comment: Yes. I want to name the post the current timestamp, and it stays that number forever.

Comment: That's a bit more complicated, so you might have to do something like in your shortcode ask Wordpress for the time the post was created instead of the time now. Or if that value isn't right for you, then store the time in e.g. a post meta field the first time the short code runs and use that value in future.

Comment: I am using a "front end user post" plugin to display a form with a hidden post-title field, and the default value should be the [timestamp] output.

Comment: But the timestamp is going to be updated with the time, so the hidden field will always be updated.  When it saves to the DB it should stay saved. When you view the created post are you still viewing it as a form?  If that's the case then you should run a check on whether or not that value already exists and if it does, don't load the hidden field.  So basically make the hidden field conditional on whether or not the `get_the_title()` is empty.

Comment: The only thing left for me to fix is that the short-code still appears as short-code in the browser title area instead of the data that should be output there.

Comment: Must be another field I need to add?